# EF Core - Conversion/Processing for relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have the following:

```cs
public class SomeClass {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Instead of having
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    // I want something like this
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; set; }

    // more properties here
}

public class Tag {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // I put this here just to show you what I want, 
    // normally EF Core will generate this for me
    public Guid SomeClassId { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to create the above scneario?
I know a good and maybe even better way to do this would be a Many-To-Many Relationship. But it would be neat to just add a new tag to the list and let EF take care of the rest of it.

I know there is Value Conversions, but I can't figure out if it is possible to apply it in this scenario. If I recall correctly you can do something like this in EF 6 with some custom mapping, but I don't see any version to do it in EF-Core.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you possibly be using C# 4 with EF Core?

Comment: Sorry, I think that one slipped through. Thanks for noticing and correcting.